# Total Execution time in MPI workshare

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to find total execution time of a parallel computation where n number of processors are working on parts of a problem. Each processor reports time taken by it. But i want to know the execution time of complete problem. How should i calculate it please help.

The code is like below. Here each process reports time taken by it.But what will be the overall time. As i guess it should not be the sum of all times because they are running in parallel

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
unsigned long long i, sum, upToVal;
unsigned long long  sumTotal;
int start, end, size, rank;
upToVal = 10;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
double t1, t2,t3,t4; 

t1 = MPI_Wtime(); 


MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
start = rank*(upToVal/size) + 1;
if(rank==(size-1)){
end = upToVal;
}else{
end = start + (upToVal/size)-1;
}
sum = 0;
sumTotal=0;
for(i=start; i<= end; i++){
sum = sum +i;
}
MPI_Reduce (&sum, &sumTotal, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD );
printf("\nRank: %d, sum: %lld, sumTotal: %lld\n", rank, sum, sumTotal);
t2=MPI_Wtime();


t3=t2-t1;

printf( "Elapsed time is %f\n", t3 );

MPI_Finalize();
```

}

Comment: Can you please define more clearly what time you want to know, e.g. CPU time vs wall time or something in between?

Comment: @Zulan . I want to measure wall time.

Comment: The code is like below. Here each process reports time taken by it.But what will be the overall time. As i guess it should not be the sum of all times because they are running in parallel